# Where can I download the dhcpd3-server source code?

Tags: dhcp

could you tell me where I can find the source code for dhcpd3-server? I know I can find the ready packages for Ubuntu/Fedora but I need to download the source code so I can..study it

Thanx in advance

Comment: why down-vote rage?

Comment: @pQd, see the down-vote tooltip?  'This question does not show research effort'.  It also doesn't seem to be particularly related to system administration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on ubuntu you can run:

```
apt-get source nameOfThePackage
```

on fedora:

```
yumdownloader --source nameOfThePackage
```